# MKLocalSearchCompleter adding region does not skew results

Tags: ios, mapkit, apple-maps, mklocalsearch

I'm currently using `MapKit`'s `MKLocalSearchCompleter` to provide an autocomplete-like functionality for users searching for a location in my iOS app, however I'm running into some serious issues with the results I'm getting back. To be more specific, my app is dealing with location information in and around Central New York and I am really trying to cater the results to locations/addresses within New York state. But for some reason typing in so much as one word will in most instances **yield results from as far away as Australia**.

`MKLocalSearchCompleter` provides a `region` attribute for influencing the object to return results near a specified region, but even that doesn't seem to be helping much.

Is there anything more I can do? Or should I consider calling it quits and moving to Google's Maps API at this point? I know Apple Maps has been notorious for erring on the side of low quality, but I didn't think I'd be subjected to only getting location results in Texas and Australia after telling their API to stick New York...

Comment: Same here, did you manage to find out why or it is a bug and makes no difference?